# Getting String Field from JSONPATH in Java

Tags: java, jsonpath

I currently have the following JSON:

```
{"content":
    [{"uuid":"123132",
    "firstname" : "Jon",
    "lastname" : "Deer"
     ...
     }
    ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is use Java to get the string value of "uuid". The following is my code:

```
JSONPATH jsonPath = new JSONPATH(json);
String myString = jsonPath.getString("content.uuid");
System.out.println(myString);
```

The resulting string: [123132]
The expected string: 123132

Is there another way to get the expected result using JSONPATH without using substring (removing the first and last characters of the string) since it is a bit more messy to look at the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to content being an `array`, "content.uuid" returns a list of string. However, as we are calling `getString()` method, that list is converted into String (using `toString()`) and hence, we are getting `[123132]` as a result.

Correct way to get the first value is `jsonPath.getString("content[0].uuid");`

Comment: And what should we do if we want to get whole string from jsonPath? When we use jsonPath.getString("$") we are getting all object inside root object. But we want whole root object.

Answer (score 1):

Return value of jsonPath is an array, which is also a valid JSON structure.  If you need the data as an other type, e.g. a String in this case, you will have to do the conversion yourself get your value#

Check this [page](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) for sample and why it returns array.

Answer (score 0):

have u ever tried `google.simple.Json` Jar ? This Jar can easily enables u to read this JSONObject Easily.

```
                       {
                         "content":
                           [{"uuid":"123132",
obj_ComplexJson ==>          "firstname" : "Jon",
                             "lastname" : "Deer"
                              ...
                            }],[],[],[]
                        }
 JSONObject obj_ComplexJson = "{"content":[{}]}""; //this json object contains your Actual Object.
JSONParser parser = new Parser();
JSONArray obj_arr = (JSONArray)parser.parse(obj_ComplexJson.get("content"));
 for(JSONObject eachObj : obj_arr){
         System.out.println(eachObj.get("uuid"));
          ..........
          ..........
     }
```

> Get Maven [JSON Simple Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1) or [Direct Jar File](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm)